# when I am executing the code only public key is generated but not the private key ,so what should I do?

Tags: java, elliptic-curve

```
package com.project;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;

public class ECCKeyGeneration {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg;
    kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC","SunEC");
    ECGenParameterSpec ecsp;
    ecsp = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp192r1");
    kpg.initialize(ecsp);

    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    PrivateKey privKey = kp.getPrivate();
    PublicKey pubKey = kp.getPublic();

    System.out.println(privKey.toString());
    System.out.println(pubKey.toString());
  }
}
```

[2] This is the code for elliptic curve cryptography for  public and private key generation but when I executed this code ,showing only the public key but not the private key,so please help me out and let me know ,what to do to generate the private key!!

Comment: Write code that generates the private key? Since we have no idea what that code does, we don't know the classes, we can just assume the implementation of getPrivate() is something like: return "";

Comment: @Stultuske please calm down... `KeyPair` is a standart java object... check it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyPair.html)

Comment: Find also [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyPair.html#getPrivate()) method `getPrivate()`

Comment: when executed ,showing --> Main.java:4: error: class ECCKeyGeneration is public, should be declared in a file named ECCKeyGeneration.java
 public class ECCKeyGeneration {
        ^
1 error  //so what to do??

Comment: Name your file as ECCKeyGeneration.java, with a try catch block.Then compile and run file. I tried your code, it works & gives both private and Public Keys.

Comment: when executed using Eclipse ,showing-->Sun EC public key, 192 bits
  public x coord: 2968371464961728379253096739591505362401590116472501032440
  public y coord: 5335329213657324346806403557586964569179386657247522228810
  parameters: secp192r1 [NIST P-192, X9.62 prime192v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.1) //but nothing about private key

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;

public class ECCKeyGeneration {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator kpg;
            kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC","SunEC");
            ECGenParameterSpec ecsp;
            ecsp = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp192r1");
            kpg.initialize(ecsp);

            KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
            PrivateKey privKey = kp.getPrivate();
            PublicKey pubKey = kp.getPublic();

            System.out.println(privKey.toString());
            System.out.println(pubKey.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I've just tested the above code.

**Output**

> **Sun EC private key, 192 bits**   private value: 
>   3248833611418544793834748156439256292267803494576663573112
>   parameters: secp192r1 [NIST P-192, X9.62 prime192v1]
>   (1.2.840.10045.3.1.1)  **Sun EC public key, 192 bits**   public x coord:
>   5122655651118956061783347731888893733494103991283417332818  public y
>   coord: 223043343028867724454216740788693823451155477884918709166
>   parameters: secp192r1 [NIST P-192, X9.62 prime192v1]
>   (1.2.840.10045.3.1.1)

Are you getting the same output?

Comment: sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl@ffffdf17
Sun EC public key, 192 bits
  public x coord: 2986437850845590154783978576780601064801052697129613842435
  public y coord: 4073070570923625270823330364164716679062682143264492286968
  parameters: secp192r1 [NIST P-192, X9.62 prime192v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.1).  @xavy:I AM NOT GETTING THE PRIVATE VALUE AS YOU MENTIONED ABOVE.

Comment: after private key , < Impl@ffffdf17 > is coming but not the value as you mentioned above <3248833611418544793834748156439256292267803494576663573112>